# Set readonly property to false for an HTML text input on clicking an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML:

```
<div class="profileForm">
    <fieldset>
    <label>Name<input type="text" id="name" name="name" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>Email<input type="email" id="email" name="email" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>Date Of Birth<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>Address<input type="text" id="address" name="address" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>City<input type="text" id="city" name="city" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>State<input type="text" id="state" name="state" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>Country<input type="text" id="country" name="country" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    <label>Access Level<input type="text" id="accessLevel" name="accessLevel" runat="server" readonly=""/></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="profileEdit">
    <fieldset>
        <label><a href="#" id="Aname">edit</a></label>
        <label><a href="#" id="Aemail">edit</a></label>
        <label><a href="#" id="Adob">edit</a></label>
        <label><a href="#" id="Aaddress">edit</a></label>
        <label><a href="#" id="Acity">edit</a></label>
        <label><a href="#" id="Astate">edit</a></label>
        <label><a href="#" id="Acountry">edit</a></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("document ready")
        $("profileEdit label a").click(
        function (e) {
            if (this.attr("id") == "Aname") {
                $("#name").attr("readonly", false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Alternate JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("document ready")
        $('#Aname').live('click', function () {
            $("#name").attr("readonly", false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is set `readonly` attribute of the corresponding input text field to false on click of the corresponding anchor field. None of my JavaScript scripts works.

Solution: after combining @KaraokeStu, @bipin answers
I am using asp.net 4.5

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("document ready")
        $('.profileEdit label a').live('click', function () {
            alert("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + this.id.substring(1, this.id.length));
            $("#" + "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + this.id.substring(1, this.id.length)).prop('readonly', false);
            console.log($("#" + "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + this.id.substring(1, this.id.length)).attr('readonly'))
            $("#" + "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" + this.id.substring(1, this.id.length)).focus();
            alert("done");
       });

    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your request. The question title reads 'set to true' while the bottom line of your question reads 'set to false'.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

change the readonly property of an element..use `prop()`

```
 $("#name").prop('readonly', false);
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/04/jquery-attr-vs-prop-difference.html) to read more about prop() and attr()

Comment: Is #name the property's name or ID?

Comment: @cullub  its ID, as you can see I am using `$("#name")` jquery id selector (`#` in front is id, `.` is class) .

Comment: readonly=false in chrome doesnt work here, only removing it completely works.

Answer (score 12):

The `readonly` attribute is a boolean. You can't set it to `true` or `false`, you can set it to `readonly` or not set it at all (`readonly=""` is wrong,  you can leave the value off (`readonly`) or specify the correct value (`readonly="readonly"`)).

If you want to change the readonly status of an element in the DOM, then set the `readonly` **property** to `true` or `false`. Leave the attribute alone.

```js
$("#name").prop("readonly", false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=name readonly>
```

Comment: Does this work if you start with readonly = "readonly"? I.e. instead of just readonly with no value?

Comment: Yes. That's completely equivalent HTML.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without jQuery:

Set `readOnly`:

```
document.getElementById("name").readOnly = true;
```

and unset:

```
document.getElementById("name").readOnly = false;
```

Everything in pure [Vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636194/4217744).

Answer (score 5):

You either do this:

```
$(selector).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
$(selector).removeAttr('readonly');
```

Or this:

```
$(selector).prop('readonly', true);
$(selector).prop('readonly', false);
```

**Never** mix the two.

It's not hard to memorize. Just remember when using .attr(), you're dealing with Attribute values. When using .prop(), you're dealing with the DOM properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $("#name").removeAttr('readonly');
```

See [**here.**](http://jetlogs.org/2007/12/16/jquery-disabled-and-readonly-inputs/)

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/oxiki)

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the `readonly` to false, you need to complete remove the attribute from the input field:

```
$("#name").removeAttr("readonly");
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with the provided answer, in order to complete the description of the `readonly` attribute, as a ***boolean attribute***, would like to mention that, contrarily to the terminology used in classicel programming languages, where a boolean is a variable able to have two states: true or false, W3C defines a boolean attribute in the [following way](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) :

> The *presence* of a *boolean attribute* on an element represents the
> `true` value, and the *absence* of the attribute represents the
> `false` value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
> or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
> canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> ***Note: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be
> omitted altogether.***

So, the jQuery

```
$("#demo").prop('readonly', false);
```

is only a syntax to *remove* the readonly attribute

```
document.getElementById("demo").removeAttribute("readonly");
```

any other approach, like setting it to *false* or another value (like *0*) will not 'eable' the input...

Comment: In reality, it depensd on actual browser implementations. As is the case with any invalid markup. readonly="false" is invalid, therefor it's up to the browser

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.profileEdit a').click(function() {
    // extract corresponding label id
    var labelId = $(this).attr('id').split('A')[1];
    // make corresponding label readonly
    $('input#'+labelId).attr('readonly','readonly');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".profileEdit label a").each(function (e) {
        $(this).click(function (elem) {
           $("#" + this.id.substring(1,this.id.length)).attr("readonly", false); 
        });
    });    
});
</script>
```

As demonstrated here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uDCgE/

Comment: nice idea actually. your code didnt wait for the click though. you might need to remove the `each(function(e){`. also since i am using asp.net i had to add `"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_"` string to the beginning of the id as `ClientId` wouldnt work on javascript strings.

Comment: It's all fun and games when you mix client-side and server-side code, eh?

Comment: this is what i arrived at after combining your and @bipen answers.asp.net changes id's of all runat="server" controls which kinda sucks.

Answer (score -2):

set element property `readonly="readonly"`