# Can't change text after set readOnly=false IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, input, readonly

I have this sample code, and It's not working just in IE. Is there an IE bug?

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" onclick="setReadonlyfalse(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setReadonlyfalse(ed){
        ed.readOnly = false;
    }
</script>
```

I'm simulating a situation that after my grid show an editor, I receive a response from server to set my editor to readonly=false. (it was rendered with readonly=true)

**edit:**

I'm using ExtJS 3.4, and the code do this:

```
/**
 * Sets the read only state of this field.
 * @param {Boolean} readOnly Whether the field should be read only.
 */
setReadOnly : function(readOnly){
    if(this.rendered){
        this.el.dom.readOnly = readOnly;
    }
    this.readOnly = readOnly;
}
```

**edit2**:
I'm adjusted the code to be more correct

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" onclick="removeReadonly(this)" value="hehehe" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeReadonly(ed){
        ed.removeAttribute("readonly");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If this editor lost focus and receive focus again, It'll work...

Comment: You need to remove attribute instead of set it falase.
Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298281/set-readonly-property-to-false-for-an-html-text-input-on-clicking-an-anchor-tag

Comment: I'm using ExtJS, and they code set to false. But if is right to remove instead of set to false, I'll do an workarround. Thank you

Comment: @Omidam81 Note that the answers to that question just show the jQuery way (`.prop()`) of doing `ed.readOnly = false;`.

Comment: This is pure javascript way: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp

Comment: `readonly` is a boolean attribute -- in your HTML, you can either use `readonly="readonly"` or `readonly`, but not `readonly="true"`. The [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) says "Bad value true for attribute readonly on element input."

Comment: I'm changed to use removeAttribute("readOnly") insteadof set to false and nothing different happens

Comment: I'm agree with you, but nothing still changed. New edit

Comment: Now I'm using IE11, but I saw that also happens in IE10

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `readonly` attribute from the element programmatically, then set `readOnly` to `false`.

```
ed.removeAttribute('readonly'); // only needed the first time
ed.readOnly = false;
```

Yes, this is an IE bug.

Comment: Do you know if there is a bug open or somewhere described it? I searched and did not find.

Comment: @patricK: Since `readOnly` works in all other browsers and according to the standard, I conclude that IE is wrong. But I don't have *evidence* per se. Did this work?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed in the case of IE, but I considered it a bug and decided to fix on the serverside (not set readonly in this case)
Thank you